# Child view get after save Image in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, view, android-view

> Step 1) I have selected two images from gallery.
>   Step 2) After that, two images get set in collage frame.
>   Step 3) Then I select two sticker on that collage frame. 
>   Step 4) Then I save it as JPEG.
>   Step 5) Change that two sticker position on collage frame.

Is Step 5 possible in android?

Thank You in Advance.

[That Screen Short Of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0gBi.png)

Comment: If you don't want to replace already existing View.